# xstate: how can I initialize the state to a specific node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xstate

I have a multi step form that basically has these basic steps: `select services -> contact -> billing`. I display a progress bar and emit events when the user changes the step they're on, and this is my current basic pattern with xstate:

```
const formMachine = new Machine({
  id: 'form-machine',
  initial: 'selectService',
  context: {
    progress: 0,
    pathname: '/select-service',
  },
  states: {
    selectService: {
      entry: assign({
        progress: 0,
        pathname: '/select-service',
      }),
      on: {
        NEXT: 'contact',
      }
    },
    contact: {
      entry: assign({
        progress: 1 / 3,
        pathname: '/billing'
      }),
      on: {
        PREVIOUS: 'selectService',
        NEXT: 'billing',
      }
    },
    // ... there's more actions but that's the gist of it
  }
});
```

Here's the visualization:
[image]

In my react component, I watch this service for changes in `pathname` so I can push to the history

```
function SignupFormWizard() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [state, send, service] = useMachine(formMachine);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = service.subscribe((state) => {
      history.push(state.context.pathname);
    });
    return subscription.unsubscribe;
  }, [service, history]);

  // ...
}
```

However, here's the problem: whenever I revisit a route (say, I directly navigate to `/billing`), it will immediately bring me back to `/select-service`. This makes sense with my code because of the initial state, and the subscription, that it will do that.

How would I go about initializing the state machine at a specific node?

Answer (score 11):

`useMachine` hook accepts second parameter which is a configuration object. In this object you can set state using `state` key, but you will have to construct state yourself, and it would look  something like this:

```js
let createdState = State.create(stateDefinition);
let resolvedState = formMachine.resolve(state);
let [state, send, service] = useMachine(formMachine, {state: resolvedState});
```

In my opinion it works well when you need to [restore persisting state](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/states.html#persisting-state), but creating `stateDefinition` manually from scratch is just too much hustle.

What you can do, is create initial state and choose where you want to actually start:

```js
initial: {
  always: [
    {
      target: "selectService",
      cond: "isSelectServicePage",
    },
    {
      target: "contact",
      cons: "isContactPage",
    },
    {
      target: "billing",
      cond: "isBillingPage",
    },
  ],
}
```

Then, when you are starting your machine, all you have to do is set initial context value:

```js
let location = useLocation();
let [state, send, service] = useMachine(formMachine, {
  context: { pathname: location.pathname },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is *almost* correct, to be more precise, you can move to first state which will decide the next step dynamically, based on context assigned.

```
  createMachine(
    {
      id: "Inspection Machine",
      initial: 
        "decideIfNewOrExisting",
      
      states: {
        "decideIfNewOrExisting": {
          always: [
            {
              target: "initialiseJob",
              cond: "isNewJob"
            },
            {
              target: "loadExistingJob"
            }
          ]
        },
...
```